# find multiple string occurrences in Python

Tags: python, string

is there a way to do something like this?

```
if ['hel','ell','orl'] in 'hello world' :
```

I want to see if all of these strings occur in the word. If possible in a shorter way than completely writing a multiline foor loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do:

```
if all( x in 'hello world' for x in ['hel','ell','orl'] ):
    print "Found all of them"
```

The built-in functions [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) are useful for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
if all(substr in 'hello world' for substr in ('hel','ell','orl')):
    # all are contained
```

The advantage of `all()` is that it stops checking as soon as one `substr` does not match.

Answer (score 0):

A multiline `for` loop is the correct way to proceed. If you don't like how it looks in your code extract it into a function and then you just have a single line function call for the same thing.